# How to add comment to lines of multi-line command?

Tags: powershell, command, comments, multiline

I want to add comments to lines of multi-line command.
How can I do this?

Next code is wrong, but how to make it correct?

```
[string] $filter = "(&" + `
  "(objectClass=user)" + ` # User
  "(!(objectClass=computer))" + ` # Not computer
  "(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))" + ` # Active
  ")",
```

Answer (score 2):

Why is the backtick needed in this case? Just do this:

```
[string] $filter = "(&" +
  "(objectClass=user)" +  # User
  "(!(objectClass=computer))" +  # Not computer
  "(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))" +  # Active
  ")"
```

Otherwise, you cannot add comments like you wanted either with single line comments using `#` or block comments using `<#...#>` as nothing can come after the backtick when you want to signify continuity to next line.

And you do know that you can use the string formatting (`-f`) to construct strings.

Comment: Since when do `<#` and `#>` have to be on their own lines? This works for me in v2: `'test', <# this #> 'out'`

Comment: @Rynant - Right, I was mistaken. Updated answer